# Xamarin Forms Background delegate being called

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am currently using the [connectivity plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) to detect network status. What I am trying to do is when I want to send data and the device is offline I start a background task using the messaging service and respective platform specific code as shown [here](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/).

The problem I am having is the Android service has a callback that continues being called even after I have stopped the service. The code below assigns a delegate to `CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged` and should stop the service after it sends the required data when network connection is restored.

```cs
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    ...
    Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += delegate
                    {
                        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                        {          
                            if (!App.ServerManager.IsUserLoggedIn())
                            App.ServerManager.LoginUserAsync(Constants.__User);

                        //send our data
                        foreach (SampleItem s in sList)
                        {
                           try 
                           {
                               //query to see if it exists on the server
                               App.ServerManager.GetSamplesAsync();

                               Task t = App.ServerManager.SaveSampleAsync(s);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(@"                ERROR {0}", e.Message);
                            }
                        }
                        // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
                        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .SetContentTitle("Jarver Industries")
                        .SetContentText("Samples Successfuly Sent!")
                        .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.banner);

                        // Build the notification:
                        Notification notification = builder.Build();

                        // Get the notification manager:
                        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                        // Publish the notification:
                        const int notificationId = 19900203;
                        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
                        MessagingCenter.Send<BackgroundDataFinishedMessage>(this, "Done");
                        StopSelf();
                        }
                    };
                });
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong on a .NET level, but I am unsure what alternatives there are.

Comment: Could you please post the codes of send data? And please debug to check whether `StopSelf()` get executed or not.

Comment: Done, StopSelf() is definitely being executed.